# Compare Excel sheet column data, then fill data to column next if any match

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two excel sheets which I want to compare values of Column A, and fill values of column B from Sheet1 to Sheet2 if match

I want to check if any Value in Sheet1 Column A, matches any Value in Sheet2 Column A. Then copy values of cell on the right of the match (column B) of Sheet1, to Column B, Cell next to the match in Sheet2.

Values in Column A, Sheet1, are unique numbers in random Order.
Values in Column A, Sheet2, may match numbers of sheet1, in random Order.

Example

Steet1, Cell A2, has number of product, let's say "nn00" and Cell B2 has the Price of thet product, let's say 100€.

So what I need is, if there is product "nn00" found in Column A, cell A17, of Sheet2, to fill the price in B17, as found in Sheet1

Comment: Could you show what exactly you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried some functions that I found from Internet, but erased them as they didn't work at all and didn't know how to fix it to work or what changes to do. They were using vlookup in two cases and Index in another case. I should say that I am not familiar with excel at all, except the very everyday basics.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use a normal

```
=vlookup(A2;'Sheet2'!A:B;2;0)
```

?

**Edit**

I tried to give you an answer that you can copy&paste for your solution (assuming "Sheet2" has the Name "Sheet2"). If you want to know how the function works, you can look here: https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: I don't know how it works or how to use it, so I cannot make any changes to it. Also where should I paste the vlookup?  I did in sheet2 but asks me to load xls, but I only have one xls with two tabs in it... Can you break it down, I mean, what is the part that says where to look, what is the part that says what to compare, what is the part that i define what to paste and where?

Comment: As editet in the answer, the proposed solution should be copy&pasteable for you. The details of the function are explained within the article that I've linked in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I actualy changed it to **=VLOOKUP(A:A;Sheet1!A:B;2;0)** which did work for me. I wanted to grab values from Sheet1 to sheet2 and to search all column A. so Figured out I had to use A:A as a reference

Answer (score 0):

Paste the `vlookup`  as mentioned by @niklas-p in Sheet2 column B. It should work the way u want it to. But don't forget to put `=` so it should be like so:

```
= vlookup(A2;'Sheet1'!A:B;2;0)
```

So in other words, `vlookup` will search for 'A2' which is the product that you want, from 'Sheet1' (the reference sheet to search for that product) using the range 'A:B'and return the value in the same row from the second column (which is the price). The last argument (0 or FALSE) is to return an exact match. So if `vlookup` can't find the product, then it will return an error, #N/A.

Hope this will clarify.

Comment: Thanks, the = I know ;), changed the A:B to A:A only and sheet2 to sheet1 in the vlookup so it looks to see if values are in A column of sheet1.

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't see that I typed in Sheet2 instead of Sheet1. Haha nevertheless glad you came across the solution that works for you :)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So, to search a value from sheet1, column A, then check if there are any similar values in shteet2 column A, the copy vlaues from Sheet1, Column B, to Sheet2, column B I used =VLOOKUP(A:A;Sheet1!A:B;2;0).